# redirect from Asp.net chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display a pie chart in my asp.net application, for this am getting values from my sql database, I've two columns named Section,Absentees....and the valued for these columns are like

```
Section          Absentees
-------          ---------
  A                 10
 MCA                 5
```

like this, and my script is,

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="202px" Width="291px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Pie" XValueMember="Section" YValueMembers="Absentees" Legend="Legend1" Name="Series1"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Name="Legend1"></asp:Legend>
    </Legends>
</asp:Chart>
```

When I try like this, am getting the "Section" only in the Chart and in the Legend like,

[image]

I need to display the "Section" in Legend and "Absentees" count in the Chart, how can I do this?

And one more thing, is it possible to redirect to another page if I click in the chart? (for ex: if I click 5 or 10 it should redirect to someother page with the value(10 or 5) as query string) is it possble?

I just included `IsValueShownAsLabel="true"` in my Series, and the values are displaying fine, and I can redirect to some page when I click on particular label by using `LabelUrl="/Default.aspx"` like this.

Now the question is how can I pass the value as QueryString, I tried like

```
LabelUrl="/Default.aspx?value=<%# Eval("Section")%>"
```

but its showing error, am trying this chart in my WebParts control.....how can I fix this..any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here for a guide on how to create pie charts:

http://betterdashboards.wordpress.com/2009/01/19/pie-charts-in-asp-net/

On the same website you can check out the ways to provide legends in different formats:

http://betterdashboards.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/display-percentages-on-a-pie-chart/

Comment: thanks for ur valuable link, I wanna redirect to some page if I click on the chart, is it possible?

Comment: yes, handle the click event of the chart object and inside the handler you can do whatever you wish (eg. redirect to an URL)

Comment: I wanna get the Legend value(for example MCA here, and I want to pass it as query string), how to get it

Comment: what kind of error ? try String.Format("~\\Reports\\BillItemReport.aspx?value={0}",Eval("Section")).

Comment: its showing error like "{"Literal content ('<asp:Series ChartType=\"Pie\" IsValueShownAsLabel=\"true\" ValueMember=\"Sections\" \r\n YValueMembers=\"Absentees\" Legend=\"Legend1\" Name=\"Series1\" \r\n LabelUrl=String.Format(\"~\\Reports\\BillItemReport.aspx?value={0}\",Eval(\"Section\")\") ToolTip=\"#VALX\">\r\n </asp:Series>') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesCollection'."}"

Comment: The String.Format instruction should also be between <%# %> like your first version.

Comment: thanks alot Tobias I fixed the issue by changing my url as labelUrl = "/Default.aspx?projectId=#VALX", and its working fine....thanks

Comment: glad you worked it out, forgot about #VALX and #VALY, you are perfectly right.

Answer (score 0):

**to redirect from specific section of pie chart:**

Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Url="/url1";

Chart1.Series[0].Points[1].Url="/url2";

Chart1.Series[0].Points[2].Url="/url3";

**to redirect from specific legends of pie chart:**

Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].LegendUrl="/url1";

Chart1.Series[0].Points[1].LegendUrl="/url2";

Chart1.Series[0].Points[2].LegendUrl="/url3";

**so you can write:**

Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Url = Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].LegendUrl = "rptPendingBreakdown.aspx";